# Git: bare repo converted to working: undoing this

Tags: git

I fear this may be on the margins of what constitutes an acceptable SO question, but here goes anyway:

Having noticed some weirdness on my git repo, namely a new master remote branch, I logged into the remote server to take a look. The repo was created bare I assume, given that it had a .git extension.

Looking at the command history, it appears someone rather gung-ho has, as root, called the following within that repo directory:

```
git init
git add .
git commit
```

I assume that this has converted the bare repo to a working copy, added the contents of course (which, if it was a bare repo would not contain any editable source code?) and committed it to the default master.

When I clone this repo, do a pull, checkout, list remote branches etc I get just the one origin/master, and the directory just contains hooks, objects, refs, info etc. The normal things one finds under .git. No code.

I guess my question has two parts:

1) Is this a rather silly thing to have done to a bare repository or is this an acceptable usage - ie am I just cloning/pulling/checking out wrong and all is well?

2) How do we get our remote branches back?

Comment: Does the remote repo have directories `branches`, `hooks` etc. in its root directory? If so, "someone" has put a Git repo in a Git repo and the simple undo is `sudo rm -rf .git` inside it. (Could you give a directory listing of the remote repo, i.e. `ls -Al whateveritscalled.git`?)

Comment: Ha, the "someone" was definitely not me. But as they didn't seem to have the greatest grasp of git I thought it best if I try and fix it. And yeah, that's done it.

Comment: @RhodriM Congrats. I got some really scary error messages when replicating the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I more or less replicated your problem and could solve it by removing the `.git` directory that has been created as part of the `git init`. This converts the repository back to a bare one. You could try that as well. It's probably wise to make a backup of the directory in case it doesn't work.

Comment: Not if it's broken. I wasn't able to clone from this sort of double initialized repository.